# Destruction in times of Moshiach

Tags: messiah

The Gemarah in Brachos 13a talks about how each latter tribulation will be so much more trying than the earlier ones that each redemption will outshine the previous one (see Maharsha). If this is the case, wouldn't that mean that when we daven for Moshiach we are davening for extremely difficult times? (Granted they are followed by the salvation of everyone). We see from other places that the final war will be devastating like Zechariah 14 (talking about gog umagog):

> וְאָסַפְתִּ֨י אֶת־כׇּל־הַגּוֹיִ֥ם ׀ אֶֽל־יְרוּשָׁלַ֘͏ִם֮ לַמִּלְחָמָה֒
> וְנִלְכְּדָ֣ה הָעִ֗יר וְנָשַׁ֙סּוּ֙ הַבָּ֣תִּ֔ים וְהַנָּשִׁ֖ים
> (תשגלנה) [תִּשָּׁכַ֑בְנָה] וְיָצָ֞א חֲצִ֤י הָעִיר֙ בַּגּוֹלָ֔ה
> וְיֶ֣תֶר הָעָ֔ם לֹ֥א יִכָּרֵ֖ת מִן־הָעִֽיר׃  For I will gather all the
> nations to Jerusalem for war: The city shall be captured, the houses
> plundered, and the women violated; and a part of the city shall go
> into exile. But the rest of the population shall not be uprooted from
> the city.

Or Shabbos 118a:

> אָמַר רַבִּי שִׁמְעוֹן בֶּן פַּזִּי אָמַר רַבִּי יְהוֹשֻׁעַ בֶּן לֵוִי מִשּׁוּם בַּר קַפָּרָא: כָּל הַמְקַיֵּים שָׁלֹשׁ סְעוּדוֹת בְּשַׁבָּת נִיצּוֹל מִשָּׁלֹשׁ פּוּרְעָנִיּוֹת: מֵחֶבְלוֹ שֶׁל מָשִׁיחַ, וּמִדִּינָהּ שֶׁל גֵּיהִנָּם, וּמִמִּלְחֶמֶת גּוֹג וּמָגוֹג.
> Rabbi Shimon ben Pazi said that Rabbi Yehoshua ben Levi said in the name of bar Kappara: Anyone who fulfills the obligation to eat three meals on Shabbat is rescued from three punishments: From the pangs of the Messiah, i.e., the suffering that precedes the advent of Messiah, and from the judgment of Gehenna, and from the war of Gog and Magog.

Of course there are a lot more examples but the point is: clearly there is going to be a lot of destruction. How can I daven for Moshiach with all my heart, knowing that seemingly millions of Jews will die, and also probably billions of people?

Comment: Millions of Jews already have died. Why would you ch"v expect more?

Comment: Regarding prophecies of destruction, maybe consider [Mishneh Toah, Yesodei ha-Torah 10:4](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/904996/jewish/Yesodei-haTorah-Chapter-Ten.htm#v4).

Comment: Maybe look at it this way: Considering the cycles of death and destruction that have befallen the Jewish People over the last two millennia, wouldn't it have been better if one of them (the earlier the better) ended in the establishment of the Messianic Times? And now, that non of those have done so, wouldn't it be better that the next cycle do so, rather than wait for yet another cycle of death and destruction, to follow after it?

Comment: Chazal say (I don't recall where) that we are already living in the times of the chevlei Moshiach, and have been for some time. So at this point we just want it to be over with the Moshiach actually coming.

Comment: @shmosel I expect more because the gemara in brachos says so.

Comment: @Yehuda Do [Chazal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chazal) _actually_ say that _we_ are already living in the times of the chevlei Moshiach? Or, do Chazal describe what the time before the coming of the Moshiach will be like (like [at the end of Mishnah Sotah in most common printed editions](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37944&pgnum=146)), and more recent Rabbis say it applies to our times?

Comment: @TamirEvan Again, don't take me at my word on this because I have to actually hunt down the source - something Kabbalistic, not some feel-good speech from a shul melave malka - but IIRC we've been living in the actual chevlei Moshiach for a couple hundred years now.